# math.sqrt function python gives same result for two different values

Tags: python-3.x

I'm to trying to calculate the sum of cubes as part of a bigger problem, and i have got stuck at this point. In the below written code (two variations of same function), when I pass a large value such as `45001`, i get conflicting results in both the functions such as

```
import math

def cube_sum(n):
    return int(math.pow((n*(n+1)/2),2));

def cube_sum1(n):
    if n%2 != 0: return int(math.pow(n*((n+1)/2),2))
    else: return int(math.pow((n/2)*(n+1),2));

def calc:
    print('1:',cube_sum(45001));
    print('2:',cube_sum1(45001));
    print('3:',(int(45001*45002/2)**2)); # gives the correct answer
```

Even though all the print values should be same(apparently), i get the output as

```
1: 1025292944081384960
2: 1025292944081384960
3: 1025292944081385001
```

while trying to analyse, i stumbled upon the following

```
 math.sqrt(1025292944081384960) == math.sqrt(1025292944081385001) # returns true
```

what's happening here?

Comment: Integer overflow, probably

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks for pointing that out. The solution in that answers my question